# Is this language context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

In a recent test, I was asked to recognize if the below language is context  free:

$\qquad\displaystyle L = \{0^{n+m}1^{n+m}0^m \mid n,m \geq 0\}$

I think it is context free, and can be accepted by below context free grammar, where $S$ is the start symbol and $Y$ is a non-terminal:

$\qquad S \to S0 \mid Y$

$\qquad Y \to 0Y1 \mid \epsilon$

However, my answer was considered wrong and that the language $L$  is not context free.

I'm confident about my answer, but the response has got me confused. Is my understanding correct? Please let me know if I've missed something.

Comment: Your grammar accept a super-set of L (for instance `0100` is not in L and generated by `S->S0->S00->Y00->0Y100->0100`).

Comment: Oh..thanks! My grammar hasn't captured the fact that the initial 0s1s have to be equal , but also more in number than the trailing 0s..

Comment: You may want to check our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions) and many similar questions on the site (e.g. [tag:formal-languages+context-free]). Disclaimer: this may lead to fading confidence.

Comment: Pumping Lemma should suffice for this one, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ogden's lemma. Choose the word $w = 0^p1^p0^p$ for large enough $p$, and mark the rightmost $0^p$. Ogden's lemma gives you a decomposition $w = uxyzv$ with $xz$ pumpable and containing at least one marked point. Since $xz$ contains a $0$, it can't contain a $1$, as otherwise $ux^2yz^2v \notin 0^*1^*0^*$. A simple case analysis now leads to a contradiction.